# XLConnect Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java): org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, r, xlconnect

I want to use XLConnect package, however, I am facing unexpected issues.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook("file.xlsx")
Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java): org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Do you have "Java Runtime Environment (JRE), version 6 or higher"  installed. Check the vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf section 2.1

Answer (score 1):

There two possible causes to this issue that I know of:

#### Java dependency conflict

If you have installed a package that also relies on Apache POI, such as [xlsx](https://github.com/colearendt/xlsx), incorrect classes will be loaded. If you restart your R session and avoid loading the conflicting package, this issue should be avoided.

#### Failed download of java dependencies

Once you have installed XLConnect (using version 1.0.4 currently on CRAN), check that the java directory under the package's installation[0] contains the following:

```sh
ls /your/library/path/XLConnect/java/
commons-codec-1.15.jar    commons-compress.jar  curvesapi-1.06.jar  poi.jar        poi-ooxml-schemas.jar  XLConnect-1.0.3.jar
commons-collections4.jar  commons-math3.jar     ooxml-schemas.jar   poi-ooxml.jar  SparseBitSet.jar       xmlbeans.jar
```

If one of these is missing, remove the package, restart your R session, and reinstall the package. Check for any errors that occur in that last step.

[0] to find your library path, run `.libPaths()` in your R session.